# How to serve a nodeJS app via HTTPS on AWS EC2?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, https

I'm trying to run a hello world express app on an EC2 instance and serve it via HTTPS.

Here is the server code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!\n');
});
const server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});

server.keepAliveTimeout = 65000; // Ensure all inactive connections are terminated by the ALB, by setting this a few seconds higher than the ALB idle timeout
server.headersTimeout = 66000; // Ensure the headersTimeout is set higher than the keepAliveTimeout due to this nodejs regression bug: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/27363
```

I created an EC2 instance and let it run there. Additionally to get HTTPS, I fired up an Application Load Balancer with an SSL certificate. I created a listener on port 443 and forwarded it to port 3000 on my EC2. Lastly I set up a Route53 entry to point to that ALB.

All I get 24/7 is `502 Bad Gateway`. Am I missing something basic here?

How to run the most basic express server via HTTPS?

Comment: Hi you’re trying to use the HTTPS protocol on port 3000 which presumably isn’t running HTTPs, try running as HTTP

Comment: Oh god after like 5 hours I just found this by myself!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who might stumble upon this some time later:

If you wish to terminate HTTPS on the load balancer and speak HTTP to your app behind it you need to select **HTTP** as prototoll and the port of your node app when creating a target group in the console.

[image]

For some reason I thought for hours this should be **HTTPS** and **443** when I want to accept HTTPS traffic.